# difference between perl's hash and python's dictionary

Tags: python, perl

I am new to perl, at most places where hash is used a reference to python's dictionaries is given. A difference which I have noticed is that the hashes don't preserve the order of elements. I would like to know if there are some more concrete and fundamental differences between the two.

Comment: Python dictionaries don't preserve the order of elements either.

Comment: Python dictionaries don't preserve the order of elements either; they are implemented as hash tables.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The most fundamental difference is that perl hashes don't throw errors if you access elements that aren't there.

```
$ python -c 'd = {}; print("Truthy" if d["a"] else "Falsy")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
$ perl -we 'use strict; my $d = {}; print $d->{"a"} ? "Truthy\n": "Falsy\n"'
Falsy
$
```

Perl hashes auto create elements too unlike python

```
$ python -c 'd = dict(); d["a"]["b"]["c"]=1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
$ perl -we 'use strict; my $d = {};  $d->{a}{b}{c}=1'
$
```

If you are converting `perl` to `python` those are the main things that will catch you out.

Comment: You should `use strict; use warnings;` in all your Perl scripts anyway. That will also remove some of these differences. I think you will find that most of the significant differences are in other parts of the languages, like the "everything is an object" paradigm of Python, and in the exception handling.

Comment: @triplee `use strict; use warnings;` does not make any difference in this case, it forbids you to use undeclared variables, not undefined dictionary items.

Comment: You can sort-of emulate the Perl behavior with `collections.defaultdict` in Python, but you still have to actually worry about the types of objects.

Comment: For sake of completeness, I shall mention that the lax behaviour of Perl hashes can be restricted with [Hash::Util](http://p3rl.org/Hash::Util) and [autovivification](http://p3rl.org/autovivification).

Comment: Python does auto creates elements, but it will not implicitly instantiante a subdict if there isn't one yet. So 
`d = dict(); d['a'] = 1` works, and so does `d = dict(); d['a'] = dict(); d['a']['b'] = 1`

Comment: Um, **incorrect** ... ?  `perl -we'$d = {};  print $d->{a}'` says `Use of uninitialized value in print at`, of course.  The `-w` enables warnings, which is a practically required good practice.  Behavior of hashes can be tuned further with other pragmas.

Comment: @ZyX The `use warnings;` makes all the difference.  What you say goes for `strict` -- why fold `warnings` under the same? They are _very_ different. But both are invariably expected in solid code and with `warnings` the interpreter complains just fine when non-existing element is used.

Comment: @zdim No, it does not. `perl -we '$d = {};  $d->{a}{b}{c}=1'` will create a bunch of subdictionaries just fine without any warnings. Also aren’t `if (undef)` and `my_sub(undef)` some forms of using non-existing element? `use warnings` does not complain there, it only complains in some select cases. You may pass your `undef` around just fine and even pretend it is boolean, it will only complain once it reaches one of specific built-in operations which not only may be very far from where `undef` was generated, it may also be something which does not complain.

Comment: @ZyX Um, wait, this was about an undefined element of a _hash_. It's specifically about hashes, and it complains when you _use_ something that isn't there, contrary to what the post says.  Your first example is different altogether -- you _assign_, auto-generating the whole structure. Other things you state have no connection to hashes either.  I commented specifically about the statement on hashes, the exclusive topic on this page.

Comment: @ZyX    Why do you bring in all these diverse language tidbits in order to defend a **wrong statement** ("_perl hashes don't throw errors if you access elements that aren't there_")? No need for that, I didn't propagate Perl or attack Python -- that'd be nosense in my book, I don't care about Perl or Python or X.  Just tools (good tools, I like'em both).  But this is an incorrect statement and I called that. Nothing more.

Comment: @ZyX Btw, there is no `if (undef)` (??) -- you can see `if ($v)` where `$v` is `undef` ... quite like `None` (where I prefer `None` and what it comes with, btw).  But how did this come up !?  I made a simple statement: if you attempt to use a hash key  that doesn't exist you get a warning. (Enabling warnings is practically a requirement on any serious code. I won't talk if warnings aren't on.)

Comment: @zdim `if ($hash->{"non_existing_key"})` and `if (undef)` are exactly the same things in relation to the topic, but `if (undef)` is faster to write. They would not be the same if attempting to access non-existing key was producing warnings, but this is not the case. This has come up because using some value in a condition is *using* some value. And you do *not* get a warning for that.

Comment: @zdim Additionally, the statement you claim wrong says about not throwing errors if you *access* elements. You claim that it is wrong based on that perl with warnings enabled throws warnings when you *use* them which may be a few lines off. I claim that warnings when using `undef` produced after reading non-existing hash element are not *always* thrown. Also how is utilizing hash element’s mutability to write to it is not using hash element? I do not think you would have argued that if `$d->{a}` was actually an existing hash.

Comment: @ZyX Alright, a little better. But, again: (1) My first comment: the example in the post **is wrong.**  Stick a `w` there -- what you always must -- and it prints warnings.  If they meant to raise a more nuanced point about how Perl handles missing keys in _various coding scenarios_ that's something else, and they should've then, um, raised _that_ point -- explain.  They clearly didn't, it's just a mistake. (2) My other comment, to you: yes, adding warnings does make a difference, in particular in their example.  [cont'd...\

Comment: @ZyX [contd] ... now, what you say in your last comments relates to complex behavior in Perl.  Your one example evaluates a hash value in a boolean context, in which case it indeed doesn't raise a warning (a design decision for that case).  There are other cases where you won't get a warning, because presumably what you do (about a no-key) makes sense so the language goes with it.  But that's about Perl intricacies, which this answer didn't even hint at; their statement is simple and wrong as such.  And _very_ misleading_, since at best it hides a whole lot.

Comment: @ZyX  Now ... you don't like that complexity of behavior in Perl?  Fine by me.  I'm not contesting that. It's a language with a lot of complexities, used to leverage a lot of expressiveness and power -- but which one needs to understand in order to use it effectively _and correctly_. So, tricky if you will.

Comment: If you add `w` in the first example you get what is essentially a type error: attempting to perform an operation on a value which does not support it, while author talks about key error: attempting to read a missing value from a hash. I think it just makes more sense to change first example into using `if()` and add that `w` (and strict) there, meaning of the post is not going to change after that.

Comment: @ZyX Oh, I see your edit.  It's good now. It leaves out much of Perl, what can result in surprises, so I'd phrase it differently ("_Perl hashes in some contexts may not throw errors if you refer to elements which aren't there_", or such) but it's correct.  We can remove all these comments if you wish -- delete and let me know. (Or we can leave them, as you wish.)  I'd leave one of my first two, a response to your comment how warnings "_does not make any difference_"

Comment: @zdim I prefer to keep all history, needed or not.

Answer (score 9):

Another major difference is that in Python you can have (user-defined) objects as your dictionary keys. Dictionaries will use the objects' `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods to manage this.

In Perl, you can't use objects as hash keys by default. Keys are stored as strings and objects will be interpolated to strings if you try to use them as keys. (However, it's possible to use objects as keys by using a tied hash with a module such as [Tie::RefHash](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/RefHash.html).)